# How do I factor $6 - 4x - 12$?

Tags: polynomials

I need some help factoring: $6-4x-12$.

How do I solve this problem?

Aren’t I supposed to take out the GCF, which is $2$?

This is how I solved it: $2 (3-2x-6)$. When I simplified this expression, it keeps going back to $6 - 4x - 12$.

Comment: First note that $6-4x-12=-4x-6$. I'd factor that as $-2(2x-3)$

Comment: How’d you get negative -2? The GCF of 6,4, and 12 is 2!

Comment: First add the $6$ to the $-12$ to get $-6$ so $6-4x - 12 = -4x -6$.

Comment: "When I simplified this expression, it keeps going back"  Why does that surprise you?  If by "simplify" you mean multiply the terms out, then you *WANT* to get the same thing back.  If you got something *different* then you did something wrong because all of these expressions should just be different expressions for the *same* value.

Comment: $\begin{array}\\ 6 - 4x -12 =  \\ -4x -6=\\-(4x + 6)=\\ -2(2x + 3)\end{array}$

Comment: @fleablood perhaps you should post your comments as an answer?

Comment: @Ocean Sorry, that should have been $2(-2x-3)$ or (preferred by me) $-2(2x+3)$. I think it looks nicer with a leading negative sign instead of many negative signs sprinkled into the other factor.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $6-12=-6$. Thus $6-4x-12$ is the same as $-4x-6$. The common factor here is $-2$, so one gets $-2(2x+3)$ as the final result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the same answer as the comments without starting over note $-6+3=-3$ which makes what you have $2(-2x-3)$ then factor the -1 out to get $(-1)2(2x+3)=-2(2x+3)$